# Isosceles triangle inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If an isosceles triangle is inscribed in a circle, then is it's altitude always greater than the radius? If yes, then why? My sir said that if an isosceles triangle is inscribed in a circle then its altitude is always greater than the radius and passes through the centre of circle but I don't understand why it is so and is it not possible if any other triangle is possible that is isosceles and has its altitude less than the radius of circle in which it's inscribed.

Comment: If the angle opposite to the base is larger than a right angle, then the altitude is smaller.

Comment: If the triangle is inscribed in the circle *and* the circle happens to be the smallest circle that includes the triangle, then the altitude will be no less than the radius.